# Phalcon: namespace class declaration error

Tags: php, namespaces, phalcon

My folder structure is:

```
/app/config/loader.php
/app/validation/Domain.php
```

Domain.php

```
namespace Validation
{
    use Phalcon\Validation\Validator as Validator;

    class Email extends Validator
    {
        public function validate($validator, $attribute)
        {
            $result = parent::validate($validator,$attribute);

            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Loader.php

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
        'Validation'  => __DIR__ . '/../validation/'
    )
);

$loader->register();

echo '<pre><br/>';
var_dump(new Validation\Email());
die();
```

and it returns an error:

> Fatal error:  Class 'Validation\Domain\Email' not found

What i'm doing wrong?

**PS:** 
An example here http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/loader.html also does't work.

```
// Creates the autoloader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

//Register some namespaces
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
       "Example\Base"    => "vendor/example/base/",
       "Example\Adapter" => "vendor/example/adapter/",
       "Example"         => "vendor/example/",
    )
);

// register autoloader
$loader->register();

// The required class will automatically include the
// file vendor/example/adapter/Some.php
$some = new Example\Adapter\Some();
```

I created the same structure and I get an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Example\Adapter\Some' not found

Comment: To someone who has the same problem - check you class and file name (it must be the same) and check the path on existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phalcon loader has some questionable reputation. If you use composer it would often make more sense to use that for autoloading your own code via the `autoload` directive.

```
# composer.json
{

    "require": {
        "phpunit/dbunit": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
        "…": "…"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "../src"
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise the issue would be with the paths, make sure you take into account subfolders (where you config sits, where the loaded code sits, etc). It seems you need to change `'app/validation/'` to `'../../app/validation/'` – figure this out yourself. Also try setting the absolute path if that doesn't do the job using `__DIR__ . '../../app/validation/'`.

**Edit:**

In your structure you say you have `Domain.php` but loading `Domain\Email` – surely the problem is here. I also tested it locally, the only instance when the loader works is when the absolute path is provided (and given you actually have app/validator/Domain/Email.php file with a class).

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
        'Validation'  => __DIR__ . '/../../app/validation/'
    )
);
```

The advice on the composer autoloader stays up. Note how you are not using PSR-0 standard for your namespaces (`validator` starts with a lower letter, your `Validator` namespace starts with a capital), which isn't cool…

Comment: thanks for your comment. Unfortunately doesn't work - the same error

Comment: I just tried your updated example with `__DIR__ . '/../../app/validation/'`, works as expected and dumps the class. All other variations result in `Class 'Validation\Domain\Email' not found`.

Comment: And why are you loading `Email` class if you have `/app/validation/Domain.php` in your example?

Comment: Thanks guy! I fixed it. I wrote the correct code above in my post.